# How do I convert a B string to bytes?

Tags: python, string, byte

```
bstr = "b'\\xe4\\xb8\\x96\\xe7\\x95\\x8c'"
bbytes = b'\xe4\xb8\x96\xe7\x95\x8c'
```

I want to convert `bstr` to `bbytes`, how can I do?

Comment: How did you end up with that `bstr`? It might be easier to fix this at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ast.literal_eval` (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) function to evaluate this string as a python literal.

```py
import ast

bstr = "b'\\xe4\\xb8\\x96\\xe7\\x95\\x8c'"
bbytes = ast.literal_eval(bstr)
print(bbytes)  # Outputs: b'\xe4\xb8\x96\xe7\x95\x8c'
```

This function should be safe to use on user inputs (unlike `eval`), though you should probably enforce a length limit to address the warning about crashing the interpreter with long/complex inputs.

Note this will also correctly parse other valid python literals (such as `int`, `list`, etc.), so if you want to enforce that you only end up with `bytes` you should check that, e.g.

```py
if not isinstance(bbytes, bytes):
  raise ValueError("Input must be a bytes string")
```

---

Hopefully you can change the input slightly, I changed the input to escape `bstr` so the special characters aren't evaluated immediately.

If you're taking this string as user input, e.g. from `input` or from reading a file, this should already be the case.

If you don't have a properly escaped input, you'll get an exception:

```
>>> bstr = "b'\xe4\xb8\x96\xe7\x95\x8c'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(bstr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 48, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
```